# Jpanels with Gridbaglayout inside a JPanel with GridbagLayout problems

Tags: java, swing, nested, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to get the CardLayout working correctly. - I have the first "card" in my deck", which i've called firstPanel (Gridbaglayout). Inside that panel i want some other panels with the same layout (Gridbaglayout) which ofc has some components.

as example under here - I'm showing one of the JPanels with Gridbaglayout that i want inside my firstPanel (Jpanel) called textFieldForPlayers.

I hope you understand what i mean. if not i'll try to explain it more detailed. :)

```
public void run() {
        deck.setLayout(cl);
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        firstPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        thirdPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        firstPanel.add(textFieldForPlayers(humanPLayers), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        firstPanel.add(botPreferences(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        firstPanel.add(next = new JButton("Next"), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        secondPanel.add(new JLabel("Bot preferences"), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        thirdPanel.add(gamePanel, c);
        deck.add(firstPanel, "1");
        deck.add(secondPanel, "2");
        deck.add(thirdPanel, "3");
        cl.show(deck, "1");
        events();
    }
```

```
private JPanel textFieldForPlayers(int hplayers) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Name of the human players");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(text, c);
        boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        boxes.add(new JTextField());
        for (int i = 1; i <= hplayers; i++) {
            boxes.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 18));
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = i;
            panel.add(boxes.get(i), c);
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = i;
            panel.add(new JLabel("Player " + i + ": "), c);
        }

        return panel;
    }
```

[Picture 3 - This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdGBJ.png)

[image]

[Picture 4 - Should be - 1 in the top, 2 in the middle and 3 in the bottom. All of them centeret.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSr0I.png)

[image]

Comment: Why do so many use the same gridx and gridy values, all being 0? Ask yourself, does this make any sense, to put all components at the same grid spot?

Comment: Well. I've set everyone on x = 0, but for every component it goes 1 down on y-axis? :) - Maybe i've misunderstood something...

Comment: ???? Look how many times you have `c.gridy = 0;` how is this going down the y-axis? Again, I'm very confused by this.

Comment: This JPanel "firstPanel.add(textFieldForPlayers(humanPLayers), c);" i want at that exact place which is grix 0 and gridy 0.  

The two c.gridy = 0 at THE BOTTOM is for secondPanel and thirdPanel. It should not have anything to say.. :)

Comment: You are not understanding how to use GridBagLayout it seems. Have you gone through the main tutorial on this? It is quite helpful and would help you out immensely. Hang on, I'll write a quick bit on what I do for this.

Comment: Yeah i think i understand it :) It's just this nested panel / CardLayout that's confusing me a bit :) 

Thaaanks man!

Comment: What CardLayout? I see no use of CardLayout in the code above.

Comment: Wait, are you wanting to swap the JPanels with a CardLayout? If so, you need to actually use a CardLayout, and failing that, show us your attempt to use it.

Comment: Yeah. ^
Second top line: deck.setLayout(cl);

and around bottom of first pic i add the panels to this deck.

You have discord or something? :D

Comment: Yes, that changes everything. Please ignore all my comments above. Please clarify your code by showing `CardLayout cl = new CardLayout()` to remove all doubt. I'm going to delete my comments and my answer, and re-analyze the situation. Sorry I missed that, but it wasn't fully clear in the code. Please consider now and in the future, posting only [mcve] if possible.

Comment: In fact your code is behaving as if `cl` is not in fact a `CardLayout`.

Comment: It's okay. I will try that. :)

Comment: It is declared in my public class GameWindow 

 private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

Comment: Cardlayout is making a JPanel with setLayout(Cardlayout). 
Then you make your "cards" / JPanels which you add to your JPane with the cardlayout.. 
Then you can change between the "cards" inside your JPanel with the cardlayout.. :) Or am i wrong? :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't tell without a working [mcve]. It makes all the difference. We don't want to see all of it, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Okay.. I'll just see if i can fix it myself. :) Can you just tell me if my last comment was right or wrong? :)

Comment: `"Cardlayout is making a JPanel with setLayout(Cardlayout)."` -- no, this is not true. It is not "making a JPanel" as this is done via the `new` keyword, e.g., `JPanel somePanel  = new JPanel();` What that line of code does is it should set the layout of an already existing JPanel.

Comment: Is this correct? :) 

http://pastebin.com/GQLdXK58

I try to modularize my gui creation - What do you mean? :) I don't get the word modularize.. :) LIke you categorize your stuff?

Comment: No pastebin's please. Post all relevant code as edits to your question, so it's easy for all to see. Thanks.

Comment: Srry.. :) 
Like:
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
 
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
contentPane.setlayout(cl);
 
 
firstPanel.add(new JButton("1"));
secondPanel.add(new JButton("2"));
 
contentPane.add(firstPanel, "1");
contentPane.add(secondPanel, "2");
 
cl.show(contentPane, "1");
 
So now the contentPane contains 2 JPanels inside it. and now we would be seeing everything on firstPanel right? :)
 
thanks for using your time on my questions. :)

Comment: Yikes! You can't post code like that in comments as it loses formatting and is unreadable. Again, please edit your question, and put all pertinent code there. Again, best if you can post a small self-contained runnable program -- like I've posted below.

Comment: I'm using 3 classes for my program... :) How do i post that?

Comment: Simplify the 3 classes into **small** classes. Note that in my example below I too am using 3 classes! Note that you shouldn't post an answer that's not an answer. Edit your question, and show your valid [mcve]. Also if you have questions about my code, comment to my answer. I'm out of here for about 5 hours. Going to likely get drunk to forget about our recent presidential election.

Comment: Hahaha! Enjoy man! Drink a beer for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your CardLayout, cl, is not behaving as a true CardLayout, suggesting something is wrong with code not shown.  Myself, I try to modularize my gui creation, including using a separate utility method to help create gridbagconstraints if any complex constraints are needed.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridBagEg extends JPanel {
    public static final int PLAYER_COUNT = 5;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel deckPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    private NextAction nextAction = new NextAction("Next");
    private PlayerPanel playerPanel = new PlayerPanel(PLAYER_COUNT);
    private BotDifficultyPanel botDifficultyPanel = new BotDifficultyPanel();

    public GridBagEg() {
        deckPanel.add(playerPanel, PlayerPanel.NAME);
        deckPanel.add(botDifficultyPanel, BotDifficultyPanel.NAME);

        JPanel nextBtnPanel = new JPanel();
        nextBtnPanel.add(new JButton(nextAction));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(deckPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(nextBtnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public NextAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.next(deckPanel);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GridBagEg mainPanel = new GridBagEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BotDifficultyPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "bot difficulty panel";
    public static final String[] LEVELS = {"Easy", "Mid-level", "Difficult", "Holy Mother of God Difficulty"};
    private JComboBox<String> difficultyCombo = new JComboBox<>(LEVELS);

    public BotDifficultyPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        add(new JLabel("Bot Difficulty:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
        add(difficultyCombo, gbc);
    }

    public String getSelectedDifficulty() {
        String selection = (String) difficultyCombo.getSelectedItem();
        return selection;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "player panel";
    private static final String TITLE = "Name of Human Players";
    private static final int EB_GAP = 10;
    private static final int FIELD_COLUMNS = 15;
    private static final int INS_GAP = 5;
    private int playerMaxCount = 0;
    private List<JTextField> playerFields = new ArrayList<>();

    public PlayerPanel(int playerMaxCount) {
        this.playerMaxCount = playerMaxCount;

        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(TITLE);
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        for (int i = 0; i < playerMaxCount; i++) {
            JTextField playerField = new JTextField(FIELD_COLUMNS);
            playerFields.add(playerField);

            add(new JLabel("Player " + i + ":"), createGbc(0, i));
            add(playerField, createGbc(1, i));
        }
    }

    public String getFieldName(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= playerFields.size()) {
            String text = "for playerFields index of " + index;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        } else {
            return playerFields.get(index).getText();
        }
    }

    public int getPlayerMaxCount() {
        return playerMaxCount;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        // if x is 0, anchor to the left otherwise to the right
        gbc.anchor = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(INS_GAP, INS_GAP, INS_GAP, INS_GAP);
        if (x == 0) {
            gbc.insets.right = 4 * INS_GAP; // increase gap in between
        }
        return gbc;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay. You're using a lot of different terms i haven't worked or discovered yet. :) But i'll try and read it and understand it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
contentPane.setlayout(cl);


firstPanel.add(new JButton("1"));
secondPanel.add(new JButton("2"));

contentPane.add(firstPanel, "1");
contentPane.add(secondPanel, "2");

cl.show(contentPane, "1");
```

So now the contentPane contains 2 JPanels inside it. and now we would be seeing everything on firstPanel right? :)